# 元号の１桁の年数(２~９年)を、"全角"で表示させる書き方について

Tags: javascript

明けまして、おめでとうございます。

早速質問ですが、
下記のコードは、元号の１桁の年数(２~９年)を"全角"で表示させたものですが、
もっと効率的な書き方がありましたら、ご教示ください。

```
 <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
 <!--

   function newYear(){

                       var now = new Date();
                       var Wareki = now.toLocaleDateString("ja-JP-u-ca-japanese", { era: "long", year:"numeric" }).
                                    replace("年", "").
                                    replace(/(^|[^\d])1(?=$|[^\d])/, '$1元').replace(/(^|[^\d])2(?=$|[^\d])/, '$1２').replace(/(^|[^\d])3(?=$|[^\d])/, '$1３').
                                    replace(/(^|[^\d])4(?=$|[^\d])/, '$1４').replace(/(^|[^\d])5(?=$|[^\d])/, '$1５').replace(/(^|[^\d])6(?=$|[^\d])/, '$1６').
                                    replace(/(^|[^\d])7(?=$|[^\d])/, '$1７').replace(/(^|[^\d])8(?=$|[^\d])/, '$1８').replace(/(^|[^\d])9(?=$|[^\d])/, '$1９').
                                    replace(/\u200e/g, "").
                                    replace(" ", "");

                       var txtReki = Wareki + "年  ";
                           document.getElementById('newYear').innerHTML=txtReki;

     window.setTimeout("newYear()",1000);
        }
         window.onload=newYear;

 //-->
 </script>


 <BODY>

<p id='newYear'></p>
```

Comment: 効率的かどうかは分かりませんが、`now.toLocaleDateString(...).replace(/\D\d年$/, function(n){return n[0] + (n[1]=='1'?'元':String.fromCodePoint(n[1]-0+65296)) + n[2];});` など。

Comment: 具体的にコードのどのあたりが非効率だと考えていますか？

Answer (score 1):

どのような書き方を「効率的」と考えておられるのかよくわからないのですが、「数字の全角変換」だけを別関数にしておくと、「ほとんど同じコードの繰り返し」は、解消することができます。

```js
function toZenDigits(str) {
  var result = "";
  for( var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i ) {
    var ch = str.charCodeAt(i);
    if( 0x0030 <= ch && ch <= 0x0039 ) {
      ch = ch - 0x0030 + 0xFF10;
    }
    result += String.fromCharCode(ch);
  }
  return result;
}
function newYear(){
  var now = new Date();
  var wareki = now.toLocaleDateString("ja-JP-u-ca-japanese", { era: "long", year:"numeric" })
    .replace("年", "")
    .replace(/(^|[^\d])1(?=$|[^\d])/, '$1元')
    .replace(/(^|[^\d])([2-9])(?=$|[^\d])/, function(whole, era, year) {return era + toZenDigits(year);})
    .replace(/\u200e/g, "")
    .replace(" ", "");

  var txtReki = wareki + "年  ";
  document.getElementById('newYear').innerHTML=txtReki;

  window.setTimeout("newYear()",1000);
}
window.onload=newYear;
```

```html
  <span id="newYear"></span>
```

もうちょっとモダンな書き方、タイプ量が少ない書き方なんかはありそうですが、「ほとんど同じコードの繰り返し」を解消すると言うのとは別の話になるので、この辺にしておきます。